# unable to connect to MongoDB - Robomongo 0.9.0

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

Hi I am not able to connect to MongoDB using Robomongo. I am using windows 7. I am using the latest version of MongoDB.

I am getting the following error.

> Cannot connect to MongoDB(localhost), error: Unable to connect to MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

As stupid as it sounds, I did not install MongoDB on my system.